# Replace Column Values with Values from another DataFrame (or a dictionary)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| City | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Moscow | 55.7 | 37.3 |
| Paris | 48.8 | 2.2 |
| New York | 40.7 | -74.0 |
| Moscow | 55.6 | 37.4 |
| Paris | 48.9 | 2.3 |
| New York | 40.8 | -74.1 |
| Moscow | 55.8 | 37.2 |
| Paris | 48.6 | 2.0 |
| New York | 40.9 | -74.2 |

Let's say these lat/long values are completely inaccurate, so I want to replace them with actual coordinates of these cities.

I have another DataFrame (or a dictionary, if needed) that stores accurate coordinates for each City:

| City | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Moscow | 55.751244 | 37.395744 |
| Paris | 48.858093 | 2.294694 |
| New York | 40.712772 | -74.006058 |

What's the easier way to update Lat / Long values for each City in the first table using values from the 2nd table?

FYI, the actual dataset I am working with includes ~ 2 million rows with approximately 500 unique values in the 'City' field.

Answer (score 1):

Set the index of both dataframes to the same column ('City') and update `df` with `df2`, to override df1's values:

```py
df1 = df1.set_index('City')

df2 = df2.set_index('City')

df1.update(df2)

df1

                Lat       Long
City
Moscow    55.751244  37.395744
Paris     48.858093   2.294694
New York  40.712772 -74.006058
Moscow    55.751244  37.395744
Paris     48.858093   2.294694
New York  40.712772 -74.006058
Moscow    55.751244  37.395744
Paris     48.858093   2.294694
New York  40.712772 -74.006058
```